# Custom code folding in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

Is there a plugin or option to use comments to use custom code folding in visual studio instead of the ugly and non standard #pragma region? I know that in vim is possible.

I want to use something like

```
//{ My description of the region.
//}
```

Instead of

```
#pragma region Ugly and not compatible with other compilers. Will show unknown pragma warning
#pragma endregion
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the language you are targetting in VS. In C# you can use "#region" which looks neat and might be what you are looking for. Unfortunately (and for reasons not known to me) Microsoft did not support this for C++ code, and you must use "#pragma region".

There is more information on this (relating to VS 2013) here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2013/07/12/visual-studio-2013-organize-your-code-with-named-regions.aspx